# Google Maps API Zoom and bounds

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api, google-maps

Добрый вечер! 
Как сделать фичу : получаю список меток с сервера и надо что бы камера перешла к ним. 
Например 2 метки - Москва и Питер и камера едет так что бы эти 2 метки было видно, а зум был не на всю планету, а аккурат что бы было видно эти 2 метки. Как такое называется хотя бы?

Нашёл вот такой пример в доках:

```
private GoogleMap mMap; 
private LatLngBounds AUSTRALIA = new LatLngBounds(   new LatLng(-44, 113), new LatLng(-10, 154));

mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(AUSTRALIA.getCenter(),
     10));
```

Но он мне не подходит потому что там Zoom постоянно 10, а мне нужно что бы он динамически менялся в зависимости от расстояния между крайними точками, так сказать. ну или есть формула какая что бы вычислить нужный зум в зависимости от расстояния между 2х точек?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл решение:

```
private static final int PADDING_RADIUS = 180;
private void animationForAllMarkers() {
    if (latLngList != null) {
        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        for (LatLng latLng : latLngList) {
            builder.include(latLng);
        }
        LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
        CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, PADDING_RADIUS);
        googleMap.animateCamera(cu);
    }
}
```